# bash: =/opt/jdk-9.0.1/: No such file or directory - Error after adding Java Path in bashrc. Even though file is there

Tags: command-line, bash, 17.10, bashrc, jdk

I have installed JDK 9, downloaded and extracted and then installed. Now when I am adding the *PATH* variables in *bashrc* terminal is showing an error

```
bash: =/opt/jdk-9.0.1/: No such file or directory
```

Even though file is present. I have added only these lines

```
#JAVA_PATH
$JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-9.0.1
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

at the end of the *bashrc* file.
I am using ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: My Bad.  Sorry, how could I forgot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a variable you need to omit the `$`, so in your case the line has to be:

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-9.0.1
```